# Axiomatic system valid, effective but not complete.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Let A be the axiomatic system whose only axiom is the sentence  **n** $\approx$ **n** and deduction rules $\varphi \rightarrow [\varphi \vee \psi ], \psi \rightarrow [\varphi \vee \psi ], (\varphi, \psi) \rightarrow [\varphi \wedge \psi ]$.

Prove that this system is valid, effective but not complete and that the set of all the theorems of A is primitive recursive.

Do not know how to prove that the system is valid, would have to look if each rule of deduction applied the axiom is a theorem  and this is enough? to prove the incompleteness  I create a truth that is not a theorem how to do this. Thanks

Comment: For validity : you have to prove that the rules "preserve" truth, i.e. if $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are *true*, then the conclusions of the three rules are *true* also. For incompleteness : you have to prove that there is a *true* formula of the system which is **not** a theorem.

Comment: About the axiom, what is the language ? What is $n ≈ n$ ? is $n = n$, where $n$ is a *numeral* ?

Comment: Yes $n \approx n$ means equality terms $n=n$

Comment: If we assume that $\lnot$ (i.e.negation) is a symbol of the language, then to show the incompleteness of the system we have to found a formula $\varphi$ such that $\varphi$ nor $\lnot \varphi$ are provable. We may use $\lnot (n = n)$ and $\lnot \lnot (n=n)$; neither is provable, because we have no rule for introduction of $\lnot$.